# Optional field validation in Yup schema

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation, yup

I'm using `react-hook-form` with `yup` for my form validation and want some fields to be optional (null).

Following their documentation, I'm using [`nullable()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemanullable-schema) and [`optional()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemaoptional-schema) but it is still getting validated:

```
export const updateAddressSchema = yup.object({
  address: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .optional()
    .min(5, "Address must be more than 5 characters long")
    .max(255, "Address must be less than 255 characters long"),
  city: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .optional()
    .max(32, "City name must be less than 32 characters long"),
  postal_code: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .optional()
    .length(10, "Postal code must be 10 characters long"),
  phone: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .optional()
    .min(10, "Phone number must be more than 10 characters long")
    .max(20, "Phone number must be less than 20 characters long"),
});
```

Is there any right way to do this?

Comment: Its working fine, you have condition if the field is left empty then it will not validate, else it will validate because field has min, max condition. Either its empty or fall between min, max values

Comment: Well, yes it doesn't validate the empty field. But it does validate the min and max values. I'm looking for a way so it doesn't validate against min, max when the field is empty.

Comment: When field is empty it does not validate. See this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-and-yup-simple-demo-forked-ugbc85)

Comment: @Usama This is mostly weird. In my own app it does get validated against the length and min/max even when it's empty. Maybe it's because I'm using `react-hook-form` and not `formik`

Comment: True its not working with react-hook-forms, There may be other workaround for this, i'll look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Usama for their answer and solution!

I experienced another problem when using their solution. My back-end API disregards null values and returns the previous value if null values are submitted. The problem was that on initial render the text field's value was null but after selecting and typing and then deleting the typed letters to get it empty again (without submitting), its value would change to an empty string and so my API would throw an error and wouldn't update the user info.

The way I managed to fix it was to use `yup`'s `.transform()` method to transform the type from empty string to null if the text field wasn't filled:

```
export const updateAddressSchema = yup.object().shape(
  {
    address: yup.string().when("address", (value) => {
      if (value) {
        return yup
          .string()
          .min(5, "Address must be more than 5 characters long")
          .max(255, "Address must be less than 255 characters long");
      } else {
        return yup
          .string()
          .transform((value, originalValue) => {
            // Convert empty values to null
            if (!value) {
              return null;
            }
            return originalValue;
          })
          .nullable()
          .optional();
      }
    }),
    ......................
  },
  [
    ["address", "address"],
    ......................,
  ]
);
```

I really hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `.when` for conditional validation like this below. I have added only for `address` and `city` only, you can add for other like this.

```
export const updateAddressSchema = yup.object().shape({

  address: yup.string().when("address", (val, schema) => {
       if(val?.length > 0) {  //if address exist then apply min max else not
          return yup.string().min(5, "min 5").max(255, "max 255").required("Required");
       } else { 
          return yup.string().notRequired();
       }
  }),

  city: yup.string().when("city", (val, schema) => {
       if(val?.length > 0) {
          return yup.string().max(32, "max 32").required("Required");
       }
       else { 
          return yup.string().notRequired();
       }
  }),
  
 }, [
     ["address", "address"], 
     ["city", "city"], 
    ]                   //cyclic dependency
 );
```

Also, you need to add [Cyclic dependency](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/193)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It does seem to work but another weird problem I'm facing right now is that when on initial render the text fields are empty and I submit, it doesn't get validated as it should, but the moment I select and deselect a field and hit submit, it gets validated again. It seems like upon focus the text field's value changes. I might try Formik altogether if I don't find a solution for that unexpected behavior.

Comment: Then, I think you need to check length of text as well, if length > 0 then validate, else not. I have updated my answer, you can check again.

Comment: Your answer does work and I'm gonna mark it as the right solution, yet I just found out that this problem comes from my API where it doesn't accept empty string values and requires them to be null for them to get updated. I need to find a way to convert empty string values to null before submitting.

Comment: Right. In your submit function you can check if value length is 0 then set it as null.