# get current value on yup when condition

Tags: html, reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I have two date fields, start date, and end date. I would like to know how to set up a validation not to accept the start date to be higher than the end date and vice-versa.

Reading the yup documentation I saw the **when condition**, but it just gets values from other fields!

[image: Date fileds]

```
import { date, object } from 'yup';

export const yupSchema = object({
  startAt: date().typeError('Invalid date').nullable(),
  endAt: date().typeError('Invalid date').nullable(),
});
```

Comment: [usefull link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72402785)

Answer (score 7):

You can utilize `ref`'s - no `when` required.

Example code:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    arrivalDate: Yup.date().required(),
    departureDate: Yup.date().required().min(Yup.ref('arrivalDate'), 'Departure date must be after arrival date')})
```

Last time I checked `when` does not receive the current value, only the value of the sibling field you're checking.  See [this issue](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/385) on Github where someone asked this exact question.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this validation to compare these two dates,

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export const yupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  startAt: Yup.date().nullable(true).required('Start At is
  required.'),
  endAt: Yup.date()
    .nullable(true)
    .when(
      'startAt',
      (startAt, schema) =>
        startAt && schema.min(startAt, 'Start At should be later than End At')
    )
});
```