# React hook form sets empty strings which cause errors after yup validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have multiple forms using `react-hook-form` to handle all the tracking and I'm using `Yup` to validate these forms. When using the basic and easy `register` function from the rhf-package, rhf automatically sets a default string value to these fields which leads to errors when trying to validate numbers and/or select options.

Even if a default value of undefined or null is set and the yup rule is extended with `notRequired()` and `nullable()`, an error is returned.

If there a way to keep it simple and don't let react-hook-form set default values for the registered fields?

**Small demo**

[image: Edit happy-frost-yr0kk5]

Comment: you want the fields to be `nullable` and `notRequired`? check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389804/optional-field-validation-in-yup-schema/72402785#72402785)

Comment: I want two things. 1) Properties in the form without user input should be undefined/null instead of an empty string. React-hook-form automatically does this which leads to wrong data in the database. Undefined/null is different than an empty string. 2) Yup should not give an error when a value is undefined/null but I think this will be fixed with 1)

Comment: then onsubmit you may need to check if `length == 0`, convert to null or something like https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/656#issuecomment-565029942